# mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: ubuntu

I am running a Linux Ubuntu VM and I want to map a network drive from a Windows server onto the VM. 
However, I am getting the following error: 
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting

I cannot find any solution to it. I have been looking for the past 2 hours and this is driving me nuts now! I previously had a bad mount error, and fixed it by

```
apt-get install nfs-common
```

Then, I tried to restart nfs-common, thinking it was a service and after some google search, I found that it is actually a package. I found the files associated to it using the command:

```
 dpkg -L nfs-common | grep /etc/init.d
```

and got this:

```
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/statd
/etc/init.d/statd-mounting
/etc/init.d/gssd
/etc/init.d/idmapd
```

Now, I don't know where to go from here.....

Comment: I tried smbclient and get the following error: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
However, if i try with other network shares, it works perfectly fine...

Comment: ok I tried using smbmount and now it works. Why?? I don't understand what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I saw the mentioned error message when using NFS inside a Docker container. The following installation helps:

```
sudo apt install netbase
```

Reason: The file /etc/services is missing

Original source: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/1262 (Mathias Rühle, thanks so much !!!)

For googlers, this error messages happen in the given context:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
```

(The latter two when -o nfsvers=3 is used).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting the same error, here is how I fixed it. It took me one whole day of goggle 0.o

First of all, I found out that the network share is password-protected. So I used smbmount, but after some more google search, I found the following link which helped me immensely:

[Mounting smbfs Shares Permanently Help File](http://web.archive.org/web/20120704073919/http://www.justlinux.com/nhf/Filesystems/Mounting_smbfs_Shares_Permanently.html)

Right now, I am trying to figure out a way if I can encrypt my password in the credentials file. I don't like leaving my password out there "naked". :P

Comment: Link doesn't work. Next time try explaining the steps on this page so there is a permanent copy.